# Page Unresponsive: NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have been working on this project, but I decided to delete the `error.tsx` and `loading.tsx` which I initially created and also the `Nextjs` cache folder. And then I reloaded the page

But since I deleted it, and continued to work on my project, each time I save, i get this message from my chrome browser **Page Unresponsive**. I will have to close the tab and open again before it works, or probably restart my VS Code terminal by typing `npm run dev`. Please, how do I fix this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried stopping your server, deleting the `.next` folder and running `yarn dev` again?

Comment: Yes I have this issue keeps occurring

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your project/file structure?

Comment: Do all your routes have this problem? Or only the root route?

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting node_modules and yarn.lock fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my cliente component was set as async component, so I just remove the async and it work